# react-redux, change object key/value with parameters from two input fields with one actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, spread-syntax

I'm trying to change input values in the object with one action.
so the action gets key("title" and "content") value as a parameter from each input when its type. It `filler` the `note` array object `id` match with `activeId`.
Assign value `const noteValue = { [action.key]: action.value };`
when I `console.log` it shows the object with correct value however, I can't return the correct value with spread operator. I tried with `map` but it returns `boolean`. so I don't think it is the correct approach. It would be very helpful with guidance. Thank you.

component

```
<div key={id}>
  <Title
   type="text"
   defaultValue={title}
   onChange={e => editNote("title", e.target.value)}
  ></Title>
  <NoteContent
    type="text"
    defaultValue={content}
    onChange={e => editNote("content", e.target.value)}
  ></NoteContent>
</div>
```

action

```
export const editNote = (key, value) => ({
  type: EDIT_NOTE,
  key,
  value
});
```

state

```
const initialState = {
  notes: [
    {
      id: "1234",
      title: "title 1",
      content: "content 1"
    },
    {
      id: "5678",
      title: "title 2",
      content: "content 2"
    },
    {
      id: "9101112",
      title: "title 3",
      content: "content 3"
    }
  ],
  activeId: null
};
```

reducer

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVE_ID:
      return { ...state, activeId: action.activeId };
    case EDIT_NOTE:
      const note = state.notes.filter(note => note === state.activeId);
      const noteValue = { [action.key]: action.value };
      const noteArr = [...note, { ...noteValue }];
      console.log(noteArr);
      return { ...state, notes: [...state.notes, ...noteArr] };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use map and try like below**

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVE_ID:
      return { ...state, activeId: action.activeId };
    case EDIT_NOTE:
      const updatedReuslt = state.notes.map((note)=>{
        if(note.id === state.activeId){
          return {...note, [action.key] : action.value }
        } else {
          return note;
        }
      })
      return { ...state, notes:updatedResult };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sathish kumar. Your approach worked so well except there was a typo `const updateReuslt`. oh, man.. it was easier than I thought. Thank you again.